# Zend Framework-Select Prompt can't allow more than 9 options

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

When I want to use *Prompt/Select* class, if my array options has more than 9 options, I cannot select the 10th option. To select it, I've to write 10, but when I wrote 1, it submitted the select.

If we check the code, we can see those lines :

```
// Retrieve a single character
$response = parent::show();
```

Is there any possibility to display 10 options and select the 10th ?
I do not think that it's possible to do that but I prefer to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to `Zend\Console\Prompt\Select` ? If so, well, although it permits only one character, you still have at least 36 options: `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

And if you consider cases, it will goes to 62 options: `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

I bet that there are far thousands others chars around the world.

Comment: Yes, i'm referring to this class.
I did not think about those characters. But, it's not "user friendly" to write a or b or C, D... to chose a select. I thought it was possible to write 10 or 15... but it seems not .

Comment: Yeah, it don't handle two or more chars.

Comment: Sadly...
Thank you for tips.